# Where do I find the Insync log file?

Tags: sync, log, insync

When contacting the customer service of Insync they ask to send the logs where do I find them in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

***Update**: if you install the newest version of Insync you no longer have to do it. You can find it here: https://forums.insynchq.com/discussion/1964/insync-for-linux-beta-16-0-10-0/p1*

The Ubuntu version of Insync does not automatically create a log everytime it runs. To have a log you have to launch Insync from the terminal and "pipe" the app's messages to a text file that you can then share:

`insync > insync.log`

if you want to go a bit farder or you are having a lot of issues with the app, you can make it run like this each time you start your computer. Just go to the dash and start typing Startup. You will find an app called **Startup Applications**. Then click on Add and in the new window:

- Add Insync as the name
- Add this line of code in the Command box: insync > "insync-"`date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M"`.log
- If you want a reminder for the future write a comment like "Start Insync and create its log"

You can also run the same command mannually from the command line or add a subfolder to put it in a different location: 
`insync > folder1/folder2/"insync-"`date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M"`.log

The way it is written, the name of the file will change every time you run it to have the date and time it started running. This way you will have a different file each time you run it in case you have crashes or reboot the computer in the same day.

You can change the order and format of the date to suit your preferences. This is what each one of them means:

- d = Day
- m = Month
- Y = Year
- H = Hour
- M = Minutes